# count days from date from mysql table to today

Tags: php, mysql, days

I need to calculate days number from subscribing date that i have in Mysql table to today, i need the number of days.

```
table name : mytable
date field name : subdate
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$today = CURDATE();
$subdate= ('subdate');
$days = (strtotime($today) - strtotime($subdate)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
```

solved thanks :
my final query :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE country LIKE '$country' and city LIKE '$city and (datediff(CURDATE(), age))>30");
```

Comment: In mysql you can do so `SELECT DAY(NOW()) - DAY(subdate) difference FROM mytable`

Comment: This has been asked 100 times before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use datediff which returns the value in days from one date to the other

```
select datediff(day1, day2);
```

So,

```
select datediff(CURDATE(), subdate) from mytable;
```

Comment: thanks it solved my probleme, my last query now is : $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE country LIKE '$country' and city LIKE '$city and (datediff(CURDATE(), age))>30");

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$today = CURDATE();
$subdate= ('subdate');
$days = strtotime($today) - strtotime($subdate);

echo floor($days/(60*60*24));
```